# Finding Probability Density Function (pdf) for set of data

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find Probability Density Function `(pdf)` for set of data. I have matrix `(1*100000)`

I followed this procedure

Finding step size by applying `dx=[max(x)-min(x)]/N` where `N=100` is the number of steps, then I found how many number fall between `(min(x)+dx)`, and I repeated that until `x(1,100000)`. Finally, I divided the result by a total number of `points(100000)`.

But the area under the curve is not one. I do not where the error is?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Repeat until $\times (1,100000)$”, huh? You should be looking at how many numbers fall in the bin (and therefore range): $[\min(x) + n\,dx, \min(x)+(n+1)\,dx)$ for each $n=0,1,\dotsc,(N-2)$, but the $(N-1)$st bin has to be able to include the maximum, so it requires the special case
$$[\min(x)+(N-1)\,dx, \min(x)+((N-1)+1)\,dx]$$ 
which you’ll note is equivalent to
$$[\max(x)-dx,\max(x)]$$
by the substitution of the definition of $dx$ that you have.

Denote the count of numbers in the $n$th bin, $c_n$.

The probability of the $n$th bin is then given by $$p_n=\frac{\#\{\text{numbers in $n$th bin}\}}{\#\{\text{numbers in any bin}\}}
=\frac{c_n}{100000}$$

You will then find that
$$p_0+p_1+\dotsb+p_{N-1}=1$$

**Quick Note** You can actually avoid the special case by using $\min(x)-\epsilon$ instead of $\min(x)$ and $\max(x)+\epsilon$ instead of $\max(x)$ for some small $\epsilon >0$.
Then the numbers are guaranteed to fall between $(\min(x)-\epsilon,\max(x)+\epsilon)$, and any paritioning would do (as long as there is no overlap).

Comment: @Math just divide the probability of each bin by $dx$ if you want the pdf.